# SQL Server dates

Tags: sql, date, asp-classic, sql-server-2012

I use Classic ASP and SQL Server 2012. I have a program that inputs into the database using `now()`. Originally it was `formnatdatetime(now(),2)`.

For the majority of time everything was fine but for some reason (which is why I'm asking) occasionally it would put the date in the database in the wrong format. So instead of `ddmmyyyy` it would be `mmddyyyy`.

I cannot see how or why when the code is the same, the database is the same. I assume `now()` or `getdate()` in TSQL is server specific.

Comment: Don't store date/time values in the database using strings.  Use the native date/time formats.  `GETDATE()` is not "server-specific".  It returns a `datetime` value.

Comment: @GordonLinoff You're missing the point the input format is the problem as SQL Server has to make a best guess when casting to `DATETIME`. Simple way to avoid this is use `dd-mmm-yyyy` means that SQL Server doesn't confused between the day and month. OP doesn't suggest at any point that they are storing the date as `VARCHAR` in the database that is an assumption on your part.

Comment: @Lankymart  . . . The OP could just use `getdate()` inside the database, if the current time is desired.  There is no need for intermediate results or final results to use strings.

Comment: @GordonLinoff That is indeed one way to get around it *(for current datetime)* but the fundamental issue is casting the output of `Now()` to `DATETIME` which both you and [Maciej](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29582727/692942) don't touch on.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the format  function

```
SELECT FORMAT(GETDATE(),'ddMMyyyy')
```

Results:

```
11042015
```

Answer (score 0):

MS SQL Server 2012 does not know `NOW()` function! As Gordon Linoff mentioned, you need to use [GETDATE()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188383.aspx) instead!

I'd suggest to read this: [Date and Time Data Types and Functions (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186724.aspx) together with: [CAST and CONVERT (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), GETDATE(), 103) AS CustomDateFormat
-- returns: dd/mm/yyyy
```

Note that sometimes, sql server can't convert date stored as a string, so you need to use [SET DATEFORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189491%28v=sql.110%29.aspx), especially when sql server uses different date format:

```
SET DATEFORMAT dmy;
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), '11/04/2015', 121) AS NewDateTime
```

Comment: The assumptions being made here by people are disturbing, the issue as I've stated multiple times now is casting regardless of whether `Now()` is used or some other datetime formatting function for example *(SQL Server doesn't need to know about it, just needs to be able to `CAST` it to a valid `DATETIME`)*. The  `SET DATEFORMAT dmy;` is a relevant approach to getting around the issue of casting the datetime incorrectly but so is passing in a format that SQL Server can't confuse such as `dd-mmm-yyyy` because the month abbreviation can't be misconstrued as the day.